# Is there a limit for the number of consoles in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tmux

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 server. I have two `tmux` sessions with 3 and 4 windows, with `bash` running in each.

Now, I want to create one more session. The first window in that session is ok. If I try to create one more window I get the error `Create window failed: No such file or directory.`

I opened a new `ssh` connection and it stopped before prompt. I have text with Ubuntu info but no prompt in it. Now I kill one window in any `tmux` session and voilà - I can create only *one* new window or create *one* more connection for `ssh`.

So it seems like like I reached the limit of shell sessions on something like this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu? No. That would be just stupid.

However, if your "VPS" happens to be an OpenVZ-based container (as is with most too-cheap-to-be-true hosting providers), then it's *possible* that the provider has set limits on various resources, including (oddly) the number of ptys (pseudo-terminals).

Check if the file `/proc/user_beancounters` exists. If it does, it'll describe the limits applied to your "server". The [`numpty`](https://wiki.openvz.org/UBC_auxiliary_parameters#numpty) line will describe the maximum number of terminals you can open.

I've actually seen providers which set it to something as low as *two*... (One pty is needed for each SSH connection, and one for every tmux window.)

Comment: Seems thats it! Thx!

Comment: Better pay for Xen/KVM next time...